# What is the difference between higher-order logic and set theory on first-order logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

After studying logic and set theory, I realized that one of the importance of set theory is to be able to do higher-order logic in it.

However, I don’t understand the functional difference between a higher-order logic at the logic level and set theory on first-order logic.

Comment: With the appropriate axioms there are no difference.

Comment: See [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/).